# Cant get my if to work in my shellscript

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, tail

To be as simple as I can be.

I want this script to catch a line whitch say "hello" in the logfile called "out.log"..
The problem I encounter is that it always get "echo expression evaluated as false" as an output even when I know the logfile contains the line that I want

```
#!/bin/bash

SERVICE_HOME="home/username/Desktop/SMX3test"

CURRENT_USER=`whoami`

start=0

NULLPOINT=out.log
OUT=hello
LINES=20

if [ 'tail -n $LINES $NULLPOINT | grep hello' = "$OUT" ];
        then
            echo expression evaluated as true
        else
            echo expression evaluated as false
        fi
exit $start
```

Anywone with a tip or the soloution?

/Phew

#

I got it! ##

#

Pre-Final-Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

############################
# Phew's Start/stop script #
############################

SERVICE_HOME="opt/data/log/ls/smx3/"

CURRENT_USER=`whoami`


start=0

NULLPOINT=servicemix.log
OUT=NullPointerException
LINES=20
REV=$(tail -n $LINES $NULLPOINT | grep NullPointerException)



if [ $REV = "$OUT" ];
                then
                /etc/init.d/ls-smx3 stop && sleep 300 && /etc/init.d/ls-smx3 start
        else
            echo "Allting är okej!"
        fi
exit $start

#####
#END#
#####
```

Comment: Does it contain it in the last 20 lines?

Comment: `'tail -n $LINES $NULLPOINT | grep hello'` -- you've specified that as a string literal which will is not executed and will therefore never match "hello". You will need to use [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html), i.e. `"$(....)"`.

Comment: Also, are you looking for lines that consist of just the word "hello" or for lines that have the word "hello" anywhere in them?

Comment: If you want to just catch the lines containing hello, then you should use some loop to iterate over the lines, that code returns true if there is an "hello" in any of the lines.

Comment: @LtWorf He should use `grep` either way, just with different expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To grab the output of a command you should surround it with $() like this

```
A=$(uname)
echo $A
```

which is equivalent to

```
A=`uname`
echo $A
```

Comment: Thanks!
This solved it :)

#!/bin/bash

############################
# Phew's Start/stop script #
############################

SERVICE_HOME="opt/data/log/ls/smx3/"

CURRENT_USER=`whoami`


start=0

NULLPOINT=servicemix.log
OUT=NullPointerException
LINES=20
REV=$(tail -n $LINES $NULLPOINT | grep NullPointerException)



if [ $REV = "$OUT" ];
                then
                /etc/init.d/ls-smx3 stop && sleep 300 && /etc/init.d/ls-smx3 start
        else
            echo "Go back"
        fi
exit $start

#####
#END#
#####

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
if tail -n $LINES $NULLPOINT | grep hello >/dev/null; then
    echo expression evaluated as true
else
    echo expression evaluated as false
fi
```

You don't have to actually match the word (unless you explicitly want that, so you should trim '\n' and make sure that 'hello' it's the only thing on that line).

Comment: You won't need to redirect to /dev/null if you use `grep -q`

Comment: @ShawnChin: Thanks for the comment. Old habits die hard.

Comment: +1, this is the cleaner way to do it. Also, if you want to make sure the like consists *exactly* of "hello" (i.e. nothing before or after), use `grep -q '^hello$'`